# TAB key not working to switch over between textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 5 textboxes such as firstname,lastname,address,city,state. I did validation using jquery to restrict from entering number and special characters.but the problem is the TAB key is not working to switch over to the next textboxes. here is ASP.NET code

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_firstname" onkeydown="return keydown(event)" MaxLength="45" />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_lastname" onkeydown="return keydown(event)" MaxLength="45" />
        <label>Address</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ID="text_address" Rows="2" MaxLength="95"></asp:TextBox>
        <label>City</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_city" onkeydown="return keydown(event)" MaxLength="45" />
        <label>State</label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_state" onkeydown="return keydown(event)" MaxLength="45" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
function keydown(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the tab key (`9`) to your code too. Otherwise `e.preventDefault()` will block the tab jump to the next field.

```
key == 9
```

Answer (score 0):

HurraH!!! i got it ... i have to give

```
function keydown(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!((key == 8) || (key==9) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

works fine

Comment: Selva.. You need to delete your answer and mark @eisbehr answer and appreciate the effort,,,